# Setting the ggplot2::geom_bar width with a theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a ggplot2 theme and I would like it to override the default geom_bar width of 90%. Is this possible with a theme?

Also I can't even find where the default value is set in the source code. Can anyone help me find where this is set in the source code?

Comment: I don't think it's possible from theme. See source code for `GeomBar$setup_data`.

Comment: you could create your own geom for that purpose. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html